# How to use setText() in a loop for increment JTextField names

Tags: java, swing

I'm new to Java. In my program, I have got 20 JTextFields named "textField0", "textField1", "textField2", "textField3", ... like wise up to 20. I need to set texts for all those 20 fields in a loop like this..

Ex;

```
    textField0 = new JTextField();
    textField1 = new JTextField();
    textField2 = new JTextField();
    textField3 = new JTextField();

    String names[] = {"Sample text 1", "Sample text 2", "Sample text 3", "Sample text 4"};

    for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        textField[i].setText(names[i]);
    }
```

I have tried for several days and tried everything I know but no solution. I'm sorry if this is not possible with Java. Thank you.

Comment: Why did your solution fail? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: It sounds like your textfields are just fields in a class. You cannot iterate over them without using reflection unless you store references to them in a `List` or `Array`

Comment: textField[i] doesn't be recognized as a variable name. I tried textField+i but did not solved. Could you please try it ?

Comment: As long as `textField` is an array of `JTextField` objects, this should work fine. Do you get an exception? Compile error?

Comment: `textField[i]` *will* work if instead of having 20 separate fields, you have *one* field which is an array: `JTextField[] textField`. Or better, `JTextField[] textFields`. Whenever you have lots of fields which just have numeric suffixes, think about using a single field of an array or collection type instead.

Comment: Show the code where you create the `JTextField` objects please.

Comment: Create a `List` of `JTextField`s and iterate over them

Comment: You're referring to the text fields as if they are in an array  but they're not.

Comment: Thank you very much for all. I was using single JTextFields before and corrected to JTextField array. Now it works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating your `JTextField` objects like this:

```
String names[] = {"Sample text 1", "Sample text 2", "Sample text 3"};
JTextField[] textFields = new JTextField[names.length];  
for (int i=0; i<names.length; i++) {
    textFields[i] = new JTextField(names[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much I learned it. Now it works but here I have got a problem when I turn separate JTextFiels to JTextField Array. My swing does not showing the fields in Design view. (but appears when executing) Could you please help me ? here is my full code.

Comment: package Main;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class JTextFields extends JFrame {
private JPanel contentPane;
public static void main(String[] args) {
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
try {
JTextFields frame = new JTextFields();
frame.setVisible(true);
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
});
}
public JTextFields() {
setTitle("JTextFields");
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);

Comment: Sorry I see what happened. It was my first post on stack-overflow. Anyway Thanks for advise.